# conjugate of vectors

Tags: inner-products, gradient-descent

I’m reading wikipedia's
[Conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) page.

On that page, they define an inner product.

$\left<\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\right>_\mathbf{A} := \left<\mathbf{Au}, \mathbf{v}\right> $

And claimes

$\left<\mathbf{Au}, \mathbf{v}\right> = \left<\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{A^Tv}\right> $

($\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric and positive definite)

I cannot understand this process. Why is this true?

**Update**

I think I solved.

$
\left<\mathbf{Au}, \mathbf{v}\right> 
= \overline{\overline{ \left<\mathbf{Au}, \mathbf{v}\right> }}
= \overline{\overline{ \mathbf{A}\left<\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\right> }}
= \overline{\mathbf{A^T}\left<\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u}\right> }
= \overline{\left<\mathbf{A^Tv}, \mathbf{u}\right>}
= \left<\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{A^Tv}\right>
$

I hope this is right.